# How to use Sphinx with other template?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sentry

I'm want to write a documentation for my new module, and I was inspired by the docs of [sentry.io](https://docs.sentry.io/), and I find out that they are using the [Sphinx](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-node/tree/master/docs) module, but the interface isn't the default one. Is there a way to change the template, or the sentry team made that for their own purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentry has their docs open-sourced. See their [documentation contributing guidelines](https://docs.sentry.io/internal/docs/) and [repository](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-docs). However it is heavily modified, so you might want to start with something easier by using [one of the themes that comes with Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.8/theming.html) or try [others](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/18b6v0/any_freeopensource_modern_sphinx_theme_out_there/).